# How do you turn off autocorrect in Libre Office Writer?

Tags: libreoffice-writer, autocorrect

How do you turn off autocorrect in Libre Office Writer?

Sometimes I think i've turned it off then it turns out there's some feature of it that appears and wasn't turned off.

I'm wondering if there's one single option that turns it off. Or if not, then what are all the places you have to tick/untick, to turn it off completely.

Here are the options I see in the menu

[image]

No off button.

Not sure what difference is between "apply" and "while typing".

Then, if I go to autocorrect options, I see Five tabs

[image]

I had a problem where I was writing some sequences of letters like "2s2 3p1" or "s2 p3"  or things like that, and it was capitalising the s in some cases.

So I went to the exceptions tab, and unticked both "autoinclude boxes"

[image]

I looked in the options tab, do I really have to untick every single thing here in order to turn off autocorrect?

[image]

And then I saw it was doing more autocorrections, really bad ones, changing the word "energy"(which was spelt fine) to something else.

I see there's a tab  "word completion"

[image]

I've now unticked "enable word completion" and I unticked "collect words" too.

I haven't gone into the "localized options" tab.

Do I really have to untick everything in every tab to turn the thing off?!

Comment: As per https://help.libreoffice.org/6.2/en-US/text/swriter/guide/auto_off.html you should be able to simply remove the checkmark from "While Typing". Does that not work?

Comment: Also turn it off in any *template* you use.

Comment: @Peregrino69 To the question of, can that tick be removed, yes, turns out it's a checkmark and can be toggled off.  (I had thought maybe it'd only shift to another option like an option button selection). I guess that might have turned off the autocompletion (though hard to know 'cos I haven't had what looks like consistent behaviour from it even when it's on. But seems like it might work

Comment: @Peregrino69 you can post that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://help.libreoffice.org/6.2/en-US/text/swriter/guide/auto_off.html removing checkmark from the **Tools** - **AutoCorrect** - **While Typing** disables AutoCorrect completely.

**Added by barlop**

So

From

[image]

To

[image]

Comment: I think your comment was good were you to have posted it as an answer as suggeted, but you've added something about templates. Where are you getting about templates? suppose it was enabled in some template, then wouldn't that then cause a check to be there? So long as there is no check there then autocorrect is disabled, regardless of "templates".

Comment: I got it from @DrMoishe's comment. I actually agree with you, don't believe a template would affect this but as I don't have LO installed on this system I can't verify. I put it there just for completeness.

Comment: He is not a doctor, and "moishe pippik" is a  joke name. And Pippik is a joke surname, it means "belly button",.. So if you are going to refer to him by one of his names then "pippik" rather than the fake title of "Dr", , would be more appropriate. (If one is to refer to him at all)

Comment: You should have pushed him on its relevance, but anyhow, glad you removed that info that we agree isn't relevant, from your answer.

Comment: LOL :-D Well, I figured since we agree on that... Thanks for adding the images :-)

Comment: I notice that when autocorrect is off, then it doesn't make URLs blue. So currently i've just unticked pretty much everything in autocorrect except URLs. And i've put autocorrect to on!

Comment: Egad! Sometimes I wonder if the designers / engineers / etc. responsible for a product actually ever use the product...